# Who has more "diplomats", Russia or the United States?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, international-relations

Given the [current spat over diplomatic expulsions between Russia and the United States](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/kremlin-spokesman-vows-retaliation-against-us-sanctions/2016/12/29/e0126be2-ce08-11e6-b8a2-8c2a61b0436f_story.html) an interesting question is: who has more diplomats? The US expelled 35 Russian diplomats. Assuming that Russia does the same and the process continues, who will run out of diplomats first? Does the US have more diplomats in Russia, than Russia has in the US, or vice versa?

Comment: Why the quotations in the title?

Comment: @DrunkCynic Because many of the people employed by the embassies are probably not diplomats.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the US has a lot more persona non grata fodder than Russia does. According to [a story by ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/US/story?id=93757) the Russian embassy in the United States employs about 190 people while the US embassy in Russia employs 1,100.